# At least one diacritic displays correctly in the editor preview, but it doesn't in the rendered post in Firefox

Tags: bug, markdown-preview, unicode

I was just mentioning in another post that typesetters and typographers have been dealing with diacritics for a long time and it isn't hard to get to them. I was delighted to discover that my example, ̅A, works perfectly in the question editor. Edit my post and check it out. The overline is over the A just as it should be.

But it doesn't work in the final presentation where the overline is left of the A. (At least it isn't on my computer.... I'm using Firefox 90.0.2 and Windows 10.)

Apparently the editor can handle the combining diacritic, but the presentation can't? Seems to be a bit of an oversight. The combining diacritic is &#773;

This is a test of @Makyen's observation: A̅.

---

**NOTE:** I deleted this per @Makyen's suggestion, but found that the issue does *not* exist in the textarea implementation at Bugzilla, [where I reported the issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1729603). There is a difference between stackexchange.com and bugzilla.mozilla.com, and since the problem doesn't exist at bugzilla.mozilla.com, I'm compelled to leave this issue open here.

I do need to make a clarification, and I didn't realize how important it was. I didn't enter the Unicode string, I copied-and-pasted the Unicode character from amp-what.com. For the purposes of this post, if you edit my post and look at the last line, below, you'll see the problem:

This is a precise test: ̅A

---

There are two close votes as "no longer reproducible," except that it's trivially reproducible at the time of this writing.

Comment: This appears to be a typo on your part, or maybe something going wrong with your input, and combined with some unexpected display issues within a `<textarea>` in Firefox. What you have in your question is `&#773;A` (combining diacritic *before* the `A`), which produces  ̅A (the diacritic combined with the space before the "A"). What you should have is `A&#773;` (combining diacritic *after* the `A`), which produces A̅ (the diacritic combined the "A"). I would consider it a Firefox bug that what you have in your question looks OK within the `<textarea>` content (i.e. what you see where typing).

Comment: @Makyen Thank you very much. You are absolutely correct and this must be a bug in Firefox's implementation of the Textarea field. Do you recommend that I delete this post?

Comment: If it was me, I'd delete it. In addition to that, it seems like it would be a good idea to check in [Mozilla's Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/) to see if the Firefox bug has been reported, and report it if it hasn't been.

Comment: @Makyen When I wrote the bug at Bugzilla, the problem didn't happen. There appears to be a difference between StackExchange.com and bugzilla.mozilla.com that's independent of my use of the Firefox browser. I've therefore undeleted the issue because the error is here, but not there.

Comment: Note: the title of this question is the opposite of what's happening (and is lacking a bit in precision; i.e. the "preview" is generally considered to be the rendering preview which is displayed below the `<textarea>`). The display is correct in the rendered post, both the preview below the `<textarea>` and final rendering, but is not correct within the `<textarea>` that is used to enter text.

Comment: The issue is apparent with both the Consolas and DejaVu Sans Mono fonts. The other fonts in the font stack which SE uses don't display this issue (at least not on Windows 10 in Firefox). While Stack Exchange can affect this by picking a different font for the display in the `<textarea>`, which makes it reasonable to report here (although, I'd consider it unlikely to be something for which SE will make a change), the *root* issue is either within those fonts or the rendering of those specific fonts.

Comment: It would be good to re-write the title and a significant portion of the question, based on what we know at this point. The title doesn't accurately reflect the issue and a significant portion of the question is written from the inaccurate point of view that what you were seeing in the `<textarea>` was the correct rendering, whereas the actual situation is that what is displayed in the `<textarea>` is inaccurate and both what is displayed in the editor preview (located below the `<textarea>`) and in the final display after submitting the post are correct. Overall, that makes this confusing.

Comment: This has nothing to do with either SE or Firefox, it's a problem with the fonts. FWIW, for me it works correctly in the final post (when in the correct letter-diacritic order) in Firefox on Android.

Comment: I don't know what amp-what.com is or how it works, but to repeat, all the examples in your post written with actual unicode characters are in wrong order, efectively placing the diacritic above the preceding letter rather than over the A. If you are copy-pasting the diacritic, you must take extra care so that it ends up after the A, not before it.

Comment: Ok, I looked out amp-what.com, and it’s crap. It only allows to copy one character at a time rather than a longer string (e.g., a letter-diacritic pair), and when you try to copy a diacritic, it actually copies a *blank space* followed by the diacritic, thus if you just paste that, it can never work. If you want to copy-and-paste diacritic characters, you need to do it elsewhere. I don’t know what system you are on, but the Character map on my Linux box lets me write and copy letters with diacritics with no problems: A̅.

Comment: Ã just typing it on my keyboard works fine. The tilde sign, and the capital A get automagically converted into Ã.

Comment: @Luuklag But that’s quite a different character: A with a tilde, rather than A with an overline (even if in some fonts, the tilde may look like a short line).

Comment: My bad @EmilJeřábek, there is no visual difference for me.

Comment: āĀ, well here is the benefit of being a mac user. Just keep pressing the A button and a selection will pop-up for special characters based of the letter A.

Comment: @Luuklag Still not there: that’s an A with *macron*. While macron and overline are similar, the overline diacritic is generally wider (the intention is that if several letters with overline follow each other, the overlines connect to make a contiguous line). NB: as far as I am aware, Unicode does not include precomposed letters with overline, thus I would be rather surprised if the combo were available in a selection of special characters. If you can coerce your mac to offer a selection of diacritic modifiers without a base letter, that might have a better chance of success.